# nodejs/fs: writing a tar to memory buffer

Tags: node.js, fs

I need to be able to `tar` a directory, and send this to a remote endpoint via `HTTP PUT`.

I could of course create the tar, save it to disk, then read it again and send it.

But I'd rather like to create the tar, then pipe it to some buffer and send it immediately. I haven't been able to achieve this.

Code so far:

```
var tar = require('tar');
var fs = require("fs");

var path = "/home/me/uploaddir";

function getTar(path, cb) {
  var buf = new Buffer('');
  var wbuf = fs.createWriteStream(buf);
  wbuf.on("finish", function() {
    cb(buf);
  });
  tar.c({file:""},[path]).
    pipe(wbuf);
}

getTar(path, function(tar) {
   //send the tar over http
});
```

This code results in:

```
fs.js:575
  binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
          ^

TypeError: path must be a string
    at TypeError (native)
    at Object.fs.open (fs.js:575:11)
```

I've also tried using an array as buffer, no joy.

Comment: uh ? It seems like you are passing a buffer with length 0 to `fs.createWriteStream` which will eventually result to an error

Comment: I am aware of this, but, as I am first creating a tar of a directory, of which I do not know the size, how should the buffer be allocated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution

> creates the tar, then pipes it to some buffer and sends it immediately

and with [great speed](https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-fs#performance) thanks to the tar-fs library:

First install the libraries [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) for simplified requests and [`tar-fs`](https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-fs), which provides filesystem bindings for tar-stream: `npm i -S tar-fs request`

```
var tar = require('tar-fs')
var request = require('request')
var fs = require('fs')

// pack specific files in the directory
function packTar (folderName, pathsArr) {
  return tar.pack(folderName, {
    entries: pathsArr 
  })
}

// return put stream
function makePutReq (url) {
  return request.put(url)
}

packTar('./testFolder', ['test.txt', 'test1.txt'])
  .pipe(makePutReq('https://www.example.com/put'))
```

I have renamed the function names to be super verbose.

Comment: This looks good man, I am having trouble in the last step though, but it may be our PUT endpoint, so still working on it. Thanks for now

Comment: Try using https://requestb.in/ like this `.pipe(makePutReq('https://requestb.in/<unique_path_here>'))` to test if its the code or the endpoint

Comment: I get a 400 Bad Request with our endpoint, and 404 Not Found with `https://requestb.in/mylittletest'`. I am actually doing: `tar.pack(path).pipe(request.put('https://requestb.in/mylittletest').on("response", function(res) {....})` in order to actually know if the request succeeds.

Comment: the issue was with setting the content-type in the headers, so it works. thanks!